# Find $a$ and $b$ such that $4(b^3-a^3)-3(b^4-a^4)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $b-a$ gets minimum.

Tags: probability, optimization

I was solving this problem that for $f(x)=12x^2-12x^3, 0<x<1$ that is probability density function we have $P(a<X<b)=\frac{1}{2}$. So we have
$$P(a<X<b)=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}$$
with calculation I reached to this: $4(b^3-a^3)-3(b^4-a^4)=\frac{1}{2}$. But I don't know how to find $a$ and $b$ such that $b-a$ becomes minimum.

Comment: If there is no "tricky" way to do it, you can revert to "Lagrange multipliers" which should be in calculus textbooks.  Minimize $a-b$ subject to the constraint $4(a^3-b^3)-3(a^4-b^4)=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Should your equation be $4(b^3-a^3)-3(b^4-a^4)=\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Comment: Are we minimizing $a - b$ (largest interval) or $b-a$ (smallest interval)?

Comment: @GEdgar Could you explain more? I don't remember how it works

Comment: @eyeballfrog I've made some edits. I want minimize $b-a$

Comment: @user295357 You're right. I've made some changes. Thanks

Comment: There [doesn't seem to be](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimise+y-x+such+that+4%28y%5E3-x%5E3%29-3%28y%5E4-x%5E4%29%3D1%2F2%2C0%3Cx%3C1%2C0%3Cy%3C1) a simple expression for it.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire OK! Did I do something wrong? It's an exercise! It shouldn't be that difficult

Comment: Does it require you to find the smallest interval, or just any interval with an area of $1/2$?

Answer (score 2):

Let's rewrite our function in terms of $s = a + b$ and $d = b-a$. Then we have
$$
4(b^3 - a^3) + 3(b^4 - a^4) = \frac{d}{2}\left[d^2(2-3s) + 3(2-s)s^2\right] = \frac{1}{2}
$$
Now we can proceed by implicit differentiation. We can define $d(s)$ as satisfying the equation $d[d^2(2-3s) + 3(2-s)s^2] =1$. Differentiating with respect to $s$ gives
$$
\left[(2-3s)d^2+(2-s)s^2\right] d'(s)+ \left[d^2-s(4-3s)\right] = 0.
$$
When $d$ is minimized, $d'(s) = 0$, so we have at the minimum that $d^2 = s(4-3s)$. This can be used in the constraint equation to give a system of two equations in two unknowns:
$$
d^2 = s(4-3s)\\
2ds(3s^2 -6s + 4) = 1.
$$
Eliminating either variable then gives a nasty 8th order polynomial that can only be solved numerically, and doing so gives $d\approx 0.2955$. However, we can actually get a fairly good rough estimate of $d$ analytically. Since $d$ is less than $1$, $d^2$ is probably fairly small. $s$ probably isn't small, so we know from the first equation that $4 - 3s$ is small. That is, $s$ is a little less than $4/3$. Putting this into the second equation gives that $d$ should be a little more than $9/32 \approx 0.28$, which it is.

Answer (score 0):

Maple agrees with that Wolfram Alpha result...
`with(Student[MultivariateCalculus]);`
`LagrangeMultipliers(b-a,[4*(b^3-a^3)-3*(b^4-a^4)-1/2],[a,b],output=detailed);`

Omit the complex (non-real) solutions, result:

$$[a = 0.5078006996, b = 0.8033286760, lambda[1] = 0.6565853254, 
  b - a = 0.2955279764]\\
[a = -0.3147015671, b = 0.5218096119, lambda[1] = 0.6400203196, 
  b - a = 0.8365111790]
$$
These should be the minimum and maximum.

Comment: You mean isn't there an easier way? Because it's an exercise. It shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: That's why I said "if there is no tricky way".